# Calling R from Python, passing parameters, R reports: "object of type 'closure' not subsettable"

Tags: python, mysql, r, csv

I am trying to use the R package `igraph` to map mesh networks at various different locations.

The data to do this is in a MySQL database. I can query the database, write the data to a csv file, and generate the graphs I want by having R read in the csv files with no problem.

My problem is that I now need to script this process up so that it can be done at will for all 50 locations we have. Previously I was manually changing values to produce graphs peace-meal.

I am trying to use Python as my scripting language to tie everything together.

Here is the relevant bit of my Python script:

```
import mysql.connector
import csv
import subprocess
localConnection = mysql.connector.connect(xxxx)


....CODE BLOCK DEFINING SQL QUERIES OMITTED....


facilityCursor = localConnection.cursor()
wLinksCursor = localConnection.cursor()
wNodesCursor = localConnection.cursor()
gatewayCursor = localConnection.cursor()

facilityCursor.execute(facilityQuery)
facility = facilityCursor.fetchone()
while facility is not None:
    print facility[0]
    wLinksCursor.execute(weightedLinksQuery % facility[0])
    wLinks = wLinksCursor.fetchall()
    linkWriter = csv.writer(open('/tmp/weightedLinks.csv', 'w'))
    for row in wLinks:
        linkWriter.writerow(row)
    wNodesCursor.execute(weightedNodesQuery % facility[0])
    wNodes = wNodesCursor.fetchall()
    nodeWriter = csv.writer(open('/tmp/weightedNodes.csv', 'w'))
    for row in wNodes:
        nodeWriter.writerow(row)
    gatewayCursor.execute(determineGatewayQuery % facility[0])
    gateways = gatewayCursor.fetchall()
    gateWriter = csv.writer(open('/tmp/gatewayWriter.csv', 'w'))
    for row in gateways:
        gateWriter.writerow(row)

    command = 'Rscript'
    path2script = '/pathToScript/networkMapper2.R'
    args = ['/tmp/weightedLinks.csv', '/tmp/weightedNodes.csv', '/tmp/gatewayWriter.csv', facility[0]]
    cmd = [command, path2script] + args
    subprocess.Popen(cmd)
    facility = facilityCursor.fetchone()
```

And now the R script that is being called:

```
library(igraph)

wlinks <- read.csv(toString(args[1]), header=T)
wnodes <- read.csv(toString(args[2]), header=T)
gateways <- read.csv(toString(args[3]), header=T)
fac <-  toString(args[4])

gateways <- as.vector(gateways[2:14,])
nodeList <- wnodes$address
func <- function(x) {x %in% gateways}
truthTable <- lapply(wnodes, func)
wnodes <- as.data.frame(cbind(wnodes,truthTable$address))

getColors <- function(x){if (x == TRUE) {x = 2} else {x = 1}}
wow <- as.matrix(lapply(wnodes$truthTable, getColors))
wnodes <- cbind(wnodes,wow)

net <- graph.data.frame(wlinks, wnodes, directed=T)
net <- simplify(net, remove.multiple = F, remove.loops = T)

E(net)$width <- E(net)$frequency/4
V(net)$size <- V(net)$frequency*0.04 + 1
V(net)$color <- gsub(TRUE, "blue", wnodes$wow)

g <- layout.fruchterman.reingold
l <- layout.kamada.kawai(net)
graphTitle <- paste("Network Visualization For ", fac, "On ", Sys.Date())
graphFileName <- paste("/tmp/", fac, "_Network_Visualization_", Sys.Date())
png(file=graphFileName, width=1500, height=1500)
plot(net, edge.color="azure4", vertex.frame.color="gray80", edge.arrow.size = 2, 
     layout=g, vertex.label=wnodes$address, vertex.label.degree=0, vertex.label.dist=0.25, 
     vertex.label.font = 2, vertex.label.cex = 1.2, vertex.label.color = "black", frame=TRUE,
     main=graphTitle)
dev.off()
```

And finally the error I'm getting when I try to run the Python script:

```
Loading required package: methods

Attaching package: ‘igraph’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    decompose, spectrum

The following object is masked from ‘package:base’:

    union

Error in args[1] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
Calls: read.csv -> read.table -> toString
Execution halted
```

Comment: `Clojure` is a computer language. `'closure'` is an R term describing the combination of a function and its lexical environment at the time of its creation. And ... `args` is an R function which is what the interpreter found looking for something named `args` and not finding anything in the search path of data objects. I think you need to look at `?commandArgs` (from an R console session.)

Comment: I would suggest looking at https://github.com/cran/argparser  (or similar) - it's quite easy to use and that way you can use flags in your python code, which would make the arguments more understandable